# Best way to remove all tabs from an Excel worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a worksheet that contains multiple cells that include a bullet point followed by a tab and then text. I want to remove all of those tabs between the bullet points and the text. What did I do and try until now to make it work:

1. Used Search & Replace: Problem is, it seems like in contrast to a .txt or .csv file I can't copy in the tab (ALT+0009) into the search field of Excel there. For .txt and .csv files it works without any problems doing it that way.
2. Looked out for formulas and found SUBSTITUTE, wrote the following formula:

   SUBSTITUTE(A1, CHAR(9),"")

That does the trick for one column. But since I have a large amount of columns and cells I need to apply that for, it would be pretty cumbersome. Is there another way or maybe a best practice on how to do that? Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to SuperUser!  Several websites I found say to use the Excel Find/Replace window and type ALT+0009 in the Find box.  **This method doesn't work in Excel 2020 (and I suspect other versions too)**.

What works for me is a one line VBA script that removes all tab characters from the selected cells.

1. Select the cells containing tab characters to remove.
2. Press ALT+F11 to open the VBE (Visual Basic Editor).
3. Paste this code into a code module, make sure the cursor is on the code and press F5 to run it.

`Sub RemoveTabsFromSelection()`

`Selection.Replace Chr$(9), vbNullString`

`End Sub`

This code replaces every tab character `Chr$(9)` in `Selection` with nothing `vbNullString` which effectively deletes them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to create a solution for my problem and explaining how to use it, it did exactly what I needed.

Comment: @RawMVC I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, while your original solution (=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(9),"") works but is somewhat tedious from dragging the function across potentially thousands of cells (I could be wrong but that is my assumption).

You can mitigate the annoying business of dragging by using CTRL + D or CTRL + R.

1.) Select the cell with the function you would like to apply.

2.) Highlight the entire selection of cells you would like to apply that function to (ex. If I wanted to apply a formula to A1 through A8, I could Lclick on A1 and then SHIFT + LClick on A8 to select the whole range).

3.) Press CTRL+D to fill the entire column or CTRL+R to fill the entire row.

More information here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/fill-a-formula-down-into-adjacent-cells-041edfe2-05bc-40e6-b933-ef48c3f308c6